# Quisiera saber que error estoy teniendo en la parte de los if comparativos entre cadenas

Tags: c++, dev-c++

> Declare una estructura llamada Disco (CD), que guarde el título, artista, numero de canciones, precio, año de lanzamiento. Declare 3 variables de tipo Disco. Use `strlen` para mostrar la longitud del artista, si es mayor a 10 letras. Luego compare si dos títulos son del mismo artista.

````
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct discoCD{
    char titulo[20];
    char artista[20];
    int ncanciones;
    float precio;
    int anio;
}disco[3];

int main(){
        **Ingresando datos**
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            fflush(stdin);
            cout<<"---Disco "<<i+1<<"---\n\n";
            cout<<"Ingrese un titulo: ";
            cin.getline(disco[i].titulo,20,'\n');
            cout<<"Ingrese nombre de artista: ";
            cin.getline(disco[i].artista,20,'\n');
            cout<<"Ingrese numero de canciones: ";
            cin>>disco[i].ncanciones;
            cout<<"Ingrese precio: ";
            cin>>disco[i].precio;
            cout<<"Ingrese anio de lanzamiento: ";
            cin>>disco[i].anio;
            cout<<"\n\n";
        }
        **Creando arreglo para longitud de nombre del artista**
        int longi[3];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            longi[i] = strlen(disco[i].artista);
        }
        
        **Mostrando los datos ingresados**
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            cout<<"---Disco "<<i+1<<"---\n\n";
            cout<<"Titulo del disco N"<<i+1<<": "<<disco[i].titulo<<endl;
            if(longi[i]>10){
                cout<<"Artista N"<<i+1<<": "<<disco[i].artista<<" con "<<longi[i]<<" letras."<<endl;
            }else{
                cout<<"Artista N"<<i+1<<": "<<disco[i].artista<<endl;
            }
            cout<<"Numero de canciones: "<<disco[i].ncanciones<<endl;
            cout<<"Precio: "<<disco[i].precio<<endl;
            cout<<"Anio de lanzamiento: "<<disco[i].anio<<endl;
            cout<<"\n\n";
        }
        
        cout<<"\n\n";
        
        
        
        **Comparando que artistas coinciden entre si**
        if(strcmp(disco[0].artista,disco[1].artista==0)){
            cout<<"El artista "<<disco[0].artista<<" coincide con dos titulos.";
        }else if(strcmp(disco[0].artista,disco[2].artista==0)){
            cout<<"El artista "<<disco[0].artista<<" coincide con dos titulos.";
        }else if(strcmp(disco[1].artista,disco[2].artista==0)){
            cout<<"El artista "<<disco[1].artista<<" coincide con dos titulos.";
        }else if(strcmp(disco[2].artista,disco[1].artista==0)){
            cout<<"El artista "<<disco[2].artista<<" coincide con dos titulos.";    
        }else{
            cout<<"Ningun artista coincide con algun titulo.";
        }
        
        cout<<"\n\n";
        
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Para empezar, el código no compila. Para acabar, el uso de `strlen` es `if (strlen(parametro, parametro) == 0)` no `if (strlen(parametro, parametro == 0))`.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Muchas gracias! Ya me di cuenta los errores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes no es de ógica, si no que es de sintaxis. Te dejo el código resuelto.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

struct discoCD{
    char titulo[20];
    char artista[20];
    int ncanciones;
    float precio;
    int anio;
}disco[3];

int main(){
        //**Ingresando datos**
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            fflush(stdin);
            cout<<"---Disco "<<i+1<<"---\n\n";
            cout<<"Ingrese un titulo: ";
            cin.getline(disco[i].titulo,20,'\n');
            cout<<"Ingrese nombre de artista: ";
            cin.getline(disco[i].artista,20,'\n');
            cout<<"Ingrese numero de canciones: ";
            cin>>disco[i].ncanciones;
            cout<<"Ingrese precio: ";
            cin>>disco[i].precio;
            cout<<"Ingrese anio de lanzamiento: ";
            cin>>disco[i].anio;
            cout<<"\n\n";
        }
        //**Creando arreglo para longitud de nombre del artista**
        int longi[3];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            longi[i] = strlen(disco[i].artista);
        }

        //**Mostrando los datos ingresados**
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            cout<<"---Disco "<<i+1<<"---\n\n";
            cout<<"Titulo del disco N"<<i+1<<": "<<disco[i].titulo<<endl;
            if(longi[i]>10){
                cout<<"Artista N"<<i+1<<": "<<disco[i].artista<<" con "<<longi[i]<<" letras."<<endl;
            }else{
                cout<<"Artista N"<<i+1<<": "<<disco[i].artista<<endl;
            }
            cout<<"Numero de canciones: "<<disco[i].ncanciones<<endl;
            cout<<"Precio: "<<disco[i].precio<<endl;
            cout<<"Anio de lanzamiento: "<<disco[i].anio<<endl;
            cout<<"\n\n";
        }

        cout<<"\n\n";



        //**Comparando que artistas coinciden entre si**
        if(strcmp(disco[0].artista,disco[1].artista) == 0){
            cout<<"El artista "<<disco[0].artista<<" coincide con los discos "<<disco[0].titulo<< " y "<<disco[1].titulo;
        }else if(strcmp(disco[0].artista,disco[2].artista) == 0){
            cout<<"El artista "<<disco[0].artista<<" coincide con los discos "<<disco[0].titulo<< " y "<<disco[2].titulo;
        }else if(strcmp(disco[1].artista,disco[2].artista) == 0){
            cout<<"El artista "<<disco[1].artista<<" coincide con los discos "<<disco[1].titulo<< " y "<<disco[2].titulo;
        }else{
            cout<<"Ningun artista coincide con algun titulo.";
        }

        cout<<"\n\n";


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Tienes un if de más en la verificación del artista, tu código está bien estructurado lo que es bueno para resolver los problemas mas rápido.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Que bien que te funcionó! :)